# Iterative merge sort

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I was asked to perform merge sort by iterative method. I solved it as follows: I first stored each of the elements of the array given in another array say $A$. Then I sent entries of $A$ two by two for merging(was given that the function for merging is known and it merged two arrays at a time). This function returned the merged array which I stored in another array $B$. After I was done with all the elements of $A$ I deleted $A$ and copied each of the entries of $B$ in $A$.I allocated memories for $A$ and $B$ dynamically. I repeated this for $log(n)$ times and each time I halved the size of $A$ and $B$. Is my algorithm correct??

Comment: have you tried to code this and try to run it?

Comment: Words overcomplicate things, you should learn to write pseudo-code.

Comment: no i haven't coded it but is it correct. i was asked only to write the algo

Comment: ["Pseudocode is an informal high-level description of the operating principle of a computer program or other algorithm."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psuedocode) It would be a way to write the algorithm. I don't know about everyone else, but I generally find pseudo-code a lot easier to read and understand than a words-only explanation (though including both probably won't hurt).

Comment: Problems of the form "here's my solution; is it correct?" are [genrally off-topic on this site](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/755).  I encourage you to read the linked discussion, the help center, and the comments here to help you edit your question to make it more suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest you try to run your algorithm on a few small arrays and see if it works.
2. Merge sort can be implemented in-place, and the same is true in your case.
3. Consider the recursive version of merge sort. Apart from calling itself recursively, the only other operation is *merge*. See if you can make a sequential list of all calls made to *merge* (with their parameters).